# Sublime snippet not scoping to HTML

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublimetext-snippet

I have the following snippet:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
<label for="my-id">Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="my-name" name="my-name" value="enter your name" />
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>htmlLabel</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>text.html</scope> 
    <description>Html Label and input</description>
</snippet>
```

It should be scoped to HTML.  It's not there when I'm in C# or Plain Text but is *IS* there in Markdown.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can fix this issue:

1. Change your `scope` to `text.html.basic`
2. Change your `scope` to `text.html -text.html.markdown`

Markdown is just a shorthand syntax for HTML. The scope for markdown is actually just `text.html.markdown`. You have `text.html` specified as your `scope`, so all the children of `text.html` are going to have access to the snippet as well.

If you want to specify a snippet for only plain HTML, you have to specify that you only want `text.html.basic` (the first method I showed), or you can negate certain scopes by using the `-` symbol (the second method I showed).

[Here](https://gist.github.com/iambibhas/4705378) is a good resource where you can see all of the different types of scope for Sublime.

Comment: That probably answers a question I had on the Sublime Text forums as well.  https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=20179